# Error while adding scopes to ServiceAccountCredentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I started to write my code to learn how to work with Google Cloud and Google Sheets.
But from the beginning this problem appeared:

```
Argument of type "list[str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "scopes" of type "str" in function "from_json_keyfile_name"
```

my code:

```py
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

credentials_file = 'creds.json'
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
     credentials_file, scope)
```

As I saw on the Internet everyone use list[str] for scopes parameter. Am I wrong?
Please help me:(

I tried to write scopes respectively but there are other parameters.
Also I checked code from: https://github.com/alexey-goloburdin/youtube-google-sheets-python/blob/master/run.py and tried to write the same code, but it did not solved the error

Comment: Odd error. Are you sure that `oauth2client` is updated to the latest version?

Comment: I tried to reinstall it once again and now I have 4.1.3 version of oauth2client, but problem is still there

Comment: By the way, it should be noted that `oauth2client` is deprecated and the GitHub repo is archived. See https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/

Comment: Oh, thanks to you I see it now. I will use another packages for my educational purposes.
Thanks again!

Comment: Please let us know if your issue has been resolved; if resolved please share the solution here as it will be useful for other team members.